# Unix Resolve sequence of variables stored in file

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

Given is a file named job.properties with below contents

```
version=current
rootDir=/a/b/c/repo
appPath=${rootDir}/${version}
workflowPath=${appPath}/workflow/test
oozie.wf.application.path=${workflowPath}/spark_scala/single_session_wf.xml
```

How to print resolved path using unix (#!/bin/ksh) or store it in variable?

**Expected output :**

```
/a/b/c/repo/current/workflow/test/spark_scala/single_session_wf.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source <(sed 's/=/="/;s/$/"/;s/^oozie.wf.application.path=/echo /' file)
```

Use sed to put double quotes around the entries after "=" and also change "oozie.wf.application.path=" to echo. Redirect the result back into source to get the desired result.

Comment: Actually file contains other parameters as well. And running above command is generating other outputs as well, so the absolute path can't be stored in variable.  

$ source <(sed 's/=/="/;s/$/"/;s/^oozie.wf.application.path=/echo /' a.prop)
oozie.use.system.libpath=true: command not found
/a/b/c/repo/current/workflow/test/spark_scala/single_session_wf.xml
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2: command not found